# How data is inserted internally in to the database?

Tags: database, oracle10g

I want to know the actuall working or the steps ocuuring while inserting the data in the database(oracle 10g)

Comment: Do you mean you want to know how Oracle handles the internal mechanics of handling the INSERT?

Comment: why o' why? Developing a new DBMS?

Answer (score 2):

You will probably find that this is a little low level for your use. But please let me know if you want anything explaining further.

http://www.mbjconsulting.com/oracle_links/oracle_internal_architecture.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of the [Oracle Concepts Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/intro.htm#i68236)